# Call to undefined method Collective

Tags: forms, laravel, facade, laravelcollective

I'm new in laravel and i have some problems with installation of collective Laravel, Despite i folow the collectiveLaravel's instalation Tutorial correctely.

```
FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 217:
Call to undefined method Collective\Html\FormFacade::open()
```

In all version (5.1, 5.2, 5.3 ) that i installe, i have the same errore when
calling form class in my sourcecode :

```
 {!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar']) !!}
    some code
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Tks for helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Form` and `HTML` facade was removed from the default installation in Laravel 5. You now need to include it yourself.

You need to grab https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/html and add `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class` to your `providers` array. See https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#installation for more details.

---

Run `composer require` in your console.

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
```

Then add the provider to your `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
],
```

Then add your aliases in `config/app.php`.

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
],
```